# Теряется второй textView в listItem при использовании swipe to dismiss в listview в android

Tags: android, listview

Есть вот такой список:
    [image: До удаления элемента]

[Код для отображения listItem](https://github.com/bulunduc/Todosha/blob/master/res/layout/list_item_task.xml)

При использовании библиотеки Swipe to dismiss [Библиотека на гитхабе](https://github.com/hudomju/android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo) верхние TextView меняются как положено, а вот TextView с датой затирается(проблема только в отображении, сами объекты в целости и сохранности), то есть если удален 1й элемент в списке, то в новом списке дата у первого элемента отображается пустой до перезапуска фрагмента(если зайти в таск и выйти, то все опять отображается нормально)

[image: После удаления]

Код, где используется библиотека и задается отображение listView

```
public class TaskListFragment extends ListFragment {
private ArrayList<Task> tasks;
private ArrayList<Task> searchTasks;

private static final String TAG = "TaskListFragment";
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    tasks = TaskLab.get(getActivity()).getTasks();
    TaskAdapter taskArrayAdapter = new TaskAdapter(tasks);
    setListAdapter(taskArrayAdapter);
}

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    View emptyView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.empty_list_tasks, null);
    ((ViewGroup)getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView);
    getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);

    ListView listView = getListView();
    final SwipeToDismissTouchListener<ListViewAdapter> touchListener =
            new SwipeToDismissTouchListener<>(
                    new ListViewAdapter(getListView()),
                    new SwipeToDismissTouchListener.DismissCallbacks<ListViewAdapter>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPendingDismiss(ListViewAdapter recyclerView, int position) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(ListViewAdapter view, int position) {
                            TaskLab.get(getActivity()).deleteTask(tasks.get(position));
                            TaskLab.get(getActivity()).saveTasks();
                            ((TaskAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    });
```

// Dismiss the item automatically after 3 seconds
        touchListener.setDismissDelay(3000);

```
    listView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    listView.setOnScrollListener((AbsListView.OnScrollListener) touchListener.makeScrollListener());
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (touchListener.existPendingDismisses()) {
                touchListener.undoPendingDismiss();
            } else {
                Task task = ((TaskAdapter) getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(TaskFragment.EXTRA_TASK_ID, task.getId());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}


private class TaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
    public TaskAdapter(ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, tasks);
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleTextView;
        TextView descriptionTextView;
        TextView alarmDateTextView;
        ViewHolder(View view) {
            titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_titleTextView);
            descriptionTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_descriptionTextView);
            alarmDateTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_alarmDateTextView);
            view.setTag(this);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        Task task = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = convertView == null
                ? new ViewHolder(convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_task, parent, false))
                : (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        viewHolder.titleTextView.setText(task.getTitle());
        viewHolder.descriptionTextView.setText(task.getDescription());
        if (task.getIsAlarmOn()) {
            SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
            viewHolder.alarmDateTextView.setText(dt.format(task.getAlarmDate()));
        }

        if (TaskLab.get(getActivity()).getLatestTasks().contains(task)) convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLatest));
        if (TaskLab.get(getActivity()).getNearestTasks().contains(task)) convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorNearest));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Глаз уже замылился, и не понимаю куда копнуть надо чтоб зафиксить. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема связана с тем, что в list_item_view для основного вида используется еще вложенный лэйаут для объединения титла и дескрипшина в одну строку.

Собственно в библиотеке:

```
assert child instanceof ViewGroup &&
                                ((ViewGroup) child).getChildCount() == 2 :
                                "Each child needs to extend from ViewGroup and have two children";
```

Поняла, что слишком замудрила с xml. Переделала на RelativeLayout